# cc1: error: unknown value ‘haswell’ for ‘-march’

Tags: drivers, 20.04, compiling, gcc, macbook-pro

I'm trying to run but it gives an error:

```
gcc -Wall -Wpedantic -std=c17 -march=haswell -c array_sum.S -o array_sum.o
cc1: error: unknown value ‘haswell’ for ‘-march’
cc1: note: valid arguments are: armv8-a armv8.1-a armv8.2-a armv8.3-a armv8.4-a armv8.5-a armv8.6-a native
```

How can I fix this?
I use parallels desktop 18 for mac - ubuntu 22.04 arm 64
the version of gcc & g++ is 11.3.0

Comment: Why are you attempting to compile it for *haswell*? Haswell is an Intel x86_64 CPU, whilst your Mac has an ARM cpu. You will not be able to run the resulting binary on your mac.

Comment: That `array_sum.S` file isn't C.  It's machine specific *assembly language* and won't run on an arm64.